# Need to define a function f[n_]

Tags: functions, function-construction

I need a defined function f[n_] satisfying

```
f[2]==Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}], 1]
f[3]==Flatten[Table[{i, j, k}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}, {k, 1, 2}], 2]
f[4]==Flatten[Table[{i, j, k, l}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}, {k, 1, 2}, {l, 1, 2}], 3]
.
.
.
etc.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use `Tuples`:

```
f[n_] := Tuples[{1, 2}, n];
```

Then:

```
f[2]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

The [Shadowray's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/146024/44141) is the right one, but just for the sake of answering directly to the question of how to build a function using exactly the commands listed in the OP:

```
f[n_Integer, imin_Integer, imax_Integer] /; (n > 0 && imin > 0 && imax > 0) := 
 Flatten[ReleaseHold@
   Block[{vars = Table[Unique[], n]}, 
    Hold[Table][#, Sequence @@ ({#, imin, imax} & /@ #)] & @ vars], 
   n - 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for something different:

```
f[n_] := IntegerDigits[Range[0, 2^n - 1], 2, n] + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

My go at this problem, as [Stitch](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/146025/1415) one, would be:

```
f[n_Integer /; n >= 1] := Flatten[Table[{##1}[[All, 1]], ##1] & @@
  Table[{Unique@"i", 1, 2}, n], n - 1]
```

Which is more easily generalizable.